# I can no longer see the format menu on this site and clicking "Discard" seems broken as well

Tags: bug, support

I click on "Ask Question" on this site and now all of the "inputs" are gone(text formatting, add link, add image, etc . .)

This site seems broken  (see screenshot below).  I am using Firefox v32 on a Mac.  Also, If I click "Discard" which I thought might "reset" my question, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Is this still an issue? I cannot recreate it myself (but I don't have a Mac). And I would expect it to have been reported by many other people over the StackExchange network. (Which it doesn't appear to have been). Have you disabled JavaScript?

Comment: I have just run into this. It happened after a saved a mockup, and I saw the same issue @leora described [here](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/it-appears-that-the-ability-to-include-a-ui-wireframe-on-this-site-is-broken). It only happens on the question I made the mockup on -- other questions show the format menu.